# PHP Trader PECL extension

Tags: php, pecl

I really want to use the trader PHP PECL extension that is available, but after several hours of work and talking with my hosting company bluehost, they say it is not possible for me to install something like this on a shared server.

So, my question is:
I have downloaded the .tar file from https://pecl.php.net/package/trader, can I somehow modify it, or use it, only using include statements? Can I copy the folder onto my server and somewhow utilize it that way?
Honestly I am completely unfamiliar with PECL and PHP extensions. What would be the best way for me to still be able to this trader extension?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Short answer no. PECL extensions need to be installed to the server meaning they will be available to all users on a shared host. That is apparently something they are not willing to do. If you must use the extension, you could use a vpn server and install whatever you want. But you then have to manage that box as well. Cost likely wouldn't be an issue because you can find vpn boxes for really cheap. Likely less than what you are paying bluehost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. PECL extensions are usually written in C, they have to be compiled and loaded as a shared object module into PHP.

If the module had been written as a PEAR package, it would be different; PEAR packages are written in PHP and can be installed as part of your application.

I doubt that there is a PEAR implementation of the trader package, because it depends on [TA-lib](http://ta-lib.org/), which is also written in C, and therefore its integration into PHP must be done through a PECL extension which [“translates” the C-based TA-lib API into PHP functions](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/trader/trunk/trader.c?view=markup).

If you really want to use this extension, you must switch to a hosting company which either already has the extension installed or is willing to do so.

By the way, if you don't need the application to be public (e.g. if you only want to do some calculations), you can set up a LAMP server in a VM on your own computer and install just any PHP extension you like.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, you can't load it into the PHP script directly like that. However, the tech support I talked to was wrong. I AM ABLE to install it on a shared server, it just took a lot of work. I followed the steps here https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/534, and updated PHP to 5.4. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Btw, good to know that there are shared hosters who allow installing PECL extensions. I agree, the procedure looks a bit complicated at first … but it's great to have command line access to the server, and it's really not much more than typing a few commands.